# If $d(x, y) = |f(x) - f(y)|$ is invariant under reflections of the real line, can we deduce $d(x, y) = \alpha |x-y|$?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-equations

Suppose $d:\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is a map such that there exists a bijective function $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ such that
$$ d(x, y) = |f(x) - f(y)|. $$
Let us call $d(x, y)$ the distance between $x$ and $y$.
Suppose the distance between points is invariant under reflections of the real line about points. That is, for all $r\in\mathbb{R}$ we have $d(x, y) = d(2r-x, 2r-y)$ (the map $x\mapsto 2r-x$ is a reflection about $r$).

Can we deduce that for some positive $\alpha$ we have $d(x, y) = \alpha|x-y|$ for all $x, y\in\mathbb{R}$?

---

**Progress So Far**

Without loss of generality, we may assume $f(0) = 0$. It helps to realize that a translation of the real line is a composition of two reflections, so our distance function is invariant under translations.

I've been able to show $f(p/q) = \delta_{1} p/q$ for all rational $p/q$ where $\delta_{1}$ is some nonzero constant. Similarly, if $\varepsilon$ is an irrational, then $f(\varepsilon p/q) = \delta_{\varepsilon}p/q$ for all rational $p/q$ where $\delta_{\varepsilon}$ is some nonzero constant.

I am left wondering if translation and reflection invariance in the way I posited above can allow me to deduce $\delta_{\varepsilon} = \delta_{1}\varepsilon$. Remember that $f$ is bijective but not necessarily continuous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There exist solutions to the functional equation $f(x+y) = f(x) + f(y)$ which are not $\mathbb{R}$-linear. (This is called Cauchy's functional equation.) As you prove, though, they are $\mathbb{Q}$-linear.

Any such $f$ gives rise to a $d$ invariant under reflections.

Comment: $f$ is a bijection?

Comment: @markvs I can choose solutions to Cacuhy's FE which are bijective; take some permutation of a Hamel basis of $\mathbb{R}$ over $\mathbb{Q}$, for instance.

Comment: You need AC for existence of Hamel basis.

Comment: @markvs Of course. But the point of this answer is that without further assumptions on $ f $ (like continuity and stuff), one cannot prove that $ f $ is necessarily linear. The sentence "Remember that $f$ is bijective but not necessarily continuous." at the end of the original post shows that this answer is very much relevant.

Comment: I do not search for points, I just read the text, and the text of the answer says that any solution of the Cauchy equation works which is not true. Whether bijective solutions even exist, is not clear (what kind of choice is needed, I do not know) and not mentioned in the answer. It is quite possible that existence of non-linear $f$ is independent from ZF.

Comment: See https://mathoverflow.net/questions/57426/are-there-any-non-linear-solutions-of-cauchys-equation-fxy-fxfy-witho and the answer there.

Comment: @markvs Technically, the text of the answer can be interpreted as correct: it only claims that for every additive $ f $, if you define $ d $ by the expression $ d ( x , y ) = | f ( x ) - f ( y ) | $, then $ d $ is invariant under reflections (no matter $ f $ is bijective or not). The existence of bijective nonlinear additive functions $ f $ is not explicitly mentioned in the post, but in the comment by the poster of the answer, replying your own comment.

Comment: @MohsenShahriari: The Q asks for a bijective function. It looks like the correctness of the answer may be independent of ZF.